# ActionScript 3 - use [brackets] instead of getChildByName

Tags: actionscript-3, casting

I have a MovieClip inside library, linkaged to `MyObject` and it contains a `textField`.
I don't know how I can access this `textField` without using the `getChildByName` method.

Apparently, the 3rd section works when object is on stage (without using `addChild`). But when using `addChild` I think there has to be some kind of casting; which I don't know how.

```
var childElement: MyObject = new MyObject();
childElement.name = "theChildElement";
container.addChild(childElement);

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeText);

function changeText(event: MouseEvent): void
{
    var targetBox:MovieClip = container.getChildByName(childElement.name) as MovieClip;
    targetBox.textField.text = "hello";  // THIS WORKS 

    // This works too:
    // MovieClip(container.getChildByName("theChildElement"))["textField"].text = "hello"; // THIS WORKS TOO.

    // THIS DOESN'T WORK. why? 
    // container["theChildElement"]["textField"].text = "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confusing as it may seem, instance name, and name are not the same. From your code you should always be able to get to your MC by it's variable name. To get your last like to work you could just use this.

```
childElement["textField"].text = "hello";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your third method doesn't work because you are trying to call the ChildElement by it's name
without using `getChildByName` method. On the other hand, you shouldn't call your textField `textField`, because that's already an actionScript property.
Your should rather call it 'displayText' for example.

For a textField called 'displayText' contained in childElement :

```
function changeText(event:MouseEvent): void
{
    childElement.displayText.text = "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between Symbols created by the Flash IDE, which aggregate other DisplayObjects and programmatically created DisplayObjects.

When a DisplayObject is created in the Flash IDE, it's instance name can be used to resolve the instance as a property - which means it can be accessed via `[]`. The `[]` can be used to access properties or keys of dynamic declared classes - like MovieClip. This necessary because you'll most likely down cast to MovieClip instead of using the symbol class created by Flash. That is not possible when simply using `addChild`, `addChildAt` or `setChildAt` from the `DisplayObjectContainer` API.

It is always the save way to access it via `getChildByName`and check for `null` because otherwise your app, website or whatever is doomed for 1009 errors as soon as someone is changing the symbols.

I'd create a bunch of helper methods, like

```
// not tested
function getChildIn(parent:DisplayObjectContainer, names:Array):DisplayObject {
  var child:DisplayObject, name:String;

  while (names.length > 0) {
    name = names.shift();
    child = parent.getChildByName(name);
    if (!child) {
      // log it
      return null;
    }
    if (names.length == 0) {
      return child;
    }
  }

  // log it
  return null;
}

function getTextFieldIn(parent:DisplayObjectContainer, names:Array):TextField {
  return getChildIn(parent, names) as TextField;
}

function getMovieClipIn(parent:DisplayObjectContainer, names:Array):MovieClip {
  return getChildIn(parent, names) as MovieClip;
}
```